# Safari 7.0.2 under Mavericks on iMac slightly changes webpage colors

Tags: css, colors, safari

I recently updated to Safari 7.0.2 (comes along with Maverick) and noticed a significant change on colors on my webpage. Namely the grey tones are darker and the css generated gradients show ugly steps, no longer fluid. Colors with Chrome under Maverick are still the same, no longer comparable to Safari. So I have to define different CSS colors to have the same results on Chrome and Safari? Weird. Never had this problem of different colors not even among other browsers (Firefox and so on, all the same)

www.stefanseifert.com

Maybe I’d have to add that I am using a custom monitor color profile.

**Edit:**
Thanks Unmut for your quick answer and your interest! What you showed me is interesting, in fact I didn’t know about this. Leaned something. Unfortunately, yet, this is not the case here. First because it isn’t about the colors within images but about the ones defined by css. (which is very very bad in my eyes)

I will try to attach 3 pics to explain. Second, yes, the difference is not big but it is significant enough for me as a designer. On the bigger pic you see 3 screenshots. The grey color as I defined it in css should be #787878. All browsers display it correctly (as also Safari did before Maverick!) Safaris grey now is deeper.

[color_difference http://www.stefanseifert.com/Color_difference.png](http://www.stefanseifert.com/Color_difference.png).

And what’s even worse are the gradients created in css (plus transparency) that show very well on all browsers (as in the first pic), but with slightly visible scales in Safari (also NOT so with Safari before Maverick) as in the last pic.

[gradient_1 http://www.stefanseifert.com/gradient_Chrome_andOthers.png](http://www.stefanseifert.com/gradient_Chrome_andOthers.png).
[gradient_2 http://www.stefanseifert.com/gradient_Safari_7.0.2.png](http://www.stefanseifert.com/gradient_Safari_7.0.2.png).

I retain this a serious problem. All around I read about Mavericks improvement of color, for me this is a great disadvantage for it doesn’t give reliable # css colors. Someone with help?

Comment: Could you share URL please? I want to try.

Comment: www.stefanseifert.com  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured one problem out, at least. I work with a customized own color profile on my iMac. And it seems that this creates the confusion. If I turn to the standard iMac profile all browsers look the same and the screenshots give the right hex color values. Yet, this is what I don’t want to do. So no real solution here for me. Somewhere I read that it depends on srgb that are not used by Safari 7, don’t know if this is true but it maybe a useful hint for someone.

For what regards the less fluid css gradients, another problem that remains. New Safari is bad at this! Much more preferable Google Chrome now, but the sad thing is that one can’t force users to use Chrome instead of Safari. All standard Mac users will use Safari I am afraid.

Second I observed performance problems in Safari with complex css transitions. It helped a little force elements around to hardware acceleration or introduce back face visibility hidden all over the place, but this is not very satisfying and good part of the lousy performance remains even with it. I thought Apple wanted to better performance of its browser, but for me it seems worse now. Everything was just fine with Safari 6 and css transitions instead. A petty.

Comment: Sorry for late answer Garavani. I learned a new problem/solution thanks to you. Glad to you find your own solition ;)

Comment: Your welcome! I think this whole Safari 7 issue is rather more complex than I thought before. And it seems a fact that Safari now is lot slower on css transitions. Hope they’ll fix that some day.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has got a problem about **Color Rendering & Color Profiles**.

Why don't you check these links:

- http://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/
- http://www.color.org/version4html.xalter
- http://news.cnet.com/Safari-ushers-in-better-browser-colors/2100-1012_3-6191815.html

**Note:** I checked it Mac OSX Mountain Lion, Safari 6.03 and i didn't see big difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

> Apple Safari Safari supports both v2 and v4 ICC profiles.
>   Unfortunately, it has no control over color on other page elements.
>   Tagged images look right, but every other page element has
>   over-saturated colors on a wide gamut LCD.

on

http://cameratico.com/guides/web-browser-color-management-guide/

Seems that Safari forces the webpage to use the full range of Monitor LCD while others like Chrome don’t. So if you changed your monitor color profile it is ignored by Safari or at least differently managed.

If you could influence on the way Safari interprets images color by tagging the images this is not possible with the rest of the elements as divs defined by CSS values.